# Intel core i7 6500 skylake - Chrome flickering/tearing

Tags: graphic-drivers, kernel, graphics, google-chrome

i buy a new Asus laptop X555UB with intel core i7 6500 and had a clean installation of loki on it.
Everything is ok, but in chrome im experimenting some flickering/tearing as the [image: attached]screenshot

I had tried disabling hardware aceleration in chrome settings and disabling flash on chrome plugins but still getting this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally with the help of the user 'I just look ilegal' do the purge of the xserver.
the steps where:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nvidia-current

sudo prime-select intel

sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-video-intel

sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and i got to fix it by 
*opening the terminal
*run upgrade
*run ¨ sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-video-intel
* run autoremove
and finally reboot

it fixed the flickering and now even the wallpaper changes all normal. no glitches anymore.

Comment: I was so skeptical about to purge the xserver, but finally give it a try and works perfectly, thanks very much!